# password in email confirmation of registration

Tags: email

When a customer signs up on my site, it receives a confirmation of registration which it is  written the username and password.
Is it regular to have the password in plain text in email?

Comment: I have just updated my answer since things have changed as of Magento 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** I just noticed that as of Magento CE 1.9.1.0 the password is no longer included in the Welcome Email. The default email template still contains `<strong>Password</strong>: {{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}`, but as part of several [security enhancements](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes#ce-19-1910-security) customer passwords are no longer stored in plain text in the database. Therefore the email will display a blank space where the password used to be. So my answer below is only applicable to Magento CE 1.9.0.1 and older.

Yes, this <strike>is</strike> was standard procedure. In `app/locale/YOURLANGUAGE/template/email/account_new.html`around line 25 you will find:

`<strong>Password</strong>: {{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}`

**Option 1:** You can change this by changing this email template and either remove this line or replace it with something like:

`The password you have chosen when creating this account.`

**Option 2:** You could also create a new email template in the Admin Panel via `System > Email Templates` and then set this new template in `System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options > Welcome Email`

Comment: thank you.i have choosen the option2.but why Magento does not change the standard procedure. For security, this practice is very dangerous!!

Comment: I totally agree with you and think Magento should change this!

Comment: It seems fix to 1.9.3.0, no ?  http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/145996/24845

Comment: It seems to have returned in the latest security update.. my customer wants it removed. Thanks for posting the solution more than 2 years ago