# password missing email new account

Tags: customer, magento-1, email-templates, customer-account

I have a new website

In the email, when I register a new user, it's missing the password:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug affecting 1.9. You can find details about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31262786/1038727

> Magento 1.9 version has problem to send password in emails. and not
>   set var values under `{{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}`
>
> There is one solution to send password in email
>
> Open the core file or extend as you like AccountController.php,  find
>   the function `createPostAction()` on line 285 or find
>
> ```
> $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
> ```
>
> just comment it like this
>
> ```
> // $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
> ```
>
> also do it in other places as on line 809, 954
>
> now it sends the password to customer new account email.
>
> ## Other method
>
> open or extend the custom model file
>
> magento\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Customer.php
>
> find the function
>
> ```
> public function cleanPasswordsValidationData()
> {
>     $this->setData('password', null);
>     $this->setData('password_confirmation', null);
>     return $this;
> }
> ```
>
> comment out `// $this->setData('password', null);`
>
> ```
> public function cleanPasswordsValidationData()
> {
>     // $this->setData('password', null);
>     $this->setData('password_confirmation', null);
>     return $this;
> }
> ```

NB: It was fixed in 1.9.3.0, see the releases notes: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1930 :

> The new customer e-mail now includes the customer's password.

Another SE link talking about it as per Vaibhav suggestion: [password in email confirmation of registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46786/password-in-email-confirmation-of-registration)

Comment: Is this bug or Magento remove this for security ?

Comment: @vaibhavahalpara it is a bug. A lot of people assumed it was removed for security reasons but this is not true. It was fixed in 1.9.3.0

Comment: ok, so I have to remove my answer :)

Comment: i used the first solution. work for me! thanks a lot!

Comment: But still, that bug is not fixed in 2.3. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think (but not checked) it's fixed by CE 1.9.3.0

In http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1930security-pwd , we can read :

> The new customer e-mail now includes the customer's password

Comment: But I can't send the password in 2.3??

Comment: @KowsiganAtsayam check this way : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/175329/24845 & the first comment => https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175328/how-to-send-customer-password-in-welcome-mail-in-magento-2#comment240766_175329