# How similar are 1.9.1 with 1.9.4? would it be possible to copy and override folders from 1.9.1 to 1.9.4?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, magento-1.9.4.0, giftmessage

We have a slightly older version of Magento (1.9.1) that is a live production site for us. We have built a newer version (1.9.4) and it's all ready to go except this one issue I need to resolve first:

We need the gift card message to appear right away so that customers don't have to click like 3 clicks to get to the form field to fill in the gift card message (for us all customers will be filling out the gift card message on every order so it only makes sense).

I have posted a couple of posts previously with this topic but the solutions provided was not that straight forward so I had someone in the real world actually help me with this. Now I can't remember how it was done and who helped me (it was back in 2015). I tried to follow some of the suggestions on how to do that but with no success!

*Now I wonder if it would be possible to just copy and override all folders and files that are responsible for how the gift card message field appears? I would be copying this from Magento 1.9.1 to Magento 1.9.4.* **Is this possible and which folders/files would you suggest I try to copy over?**

Comment: please check my answer , Let me know if you have any confusion for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to override to 1.9.1 to 1.9.4

You can find the full list of differences in the official release notes: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1940

> Side note

There used to be **a bug in Magento where the passwords would not display in the new account email template.** Most of the people (including me) assumed it was a security enhancement (see here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/46793/2380) but it was actually a bug which has been fixed in 1.9.4.0.

> PHP 7

For those using PHP 7 and the Inchoo module, Inchoo has released a new version of the module (2.0.0) which is only compatible with 1.9.4.0 don't forget to update: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

and  above extension work fine then backup your project  
after check your  magento 1.9.1 to latest magento 1.9.1 file core code difference using below command

```
diff -urbB core1.9.1 yourcode1.9.1core | lsdiff
```

*here **core1.9.1**    =>app/code/core folder(latest magento 1.9.1 core folder) 

**yourcode1.9.1core** =>app/code/core folder(your magento 1.9.1 core folder)*

also same process **js**,**lib** folder

after magento 1.9.4.0 all file and all folder override